# Connect graph DB and SQL in laravel

Tags: php, neo4j, graph-databases, laravel-5.5

I want to connect multiple databases in Laravel 5.5. I tried using [this](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections) but it doesn't seem to work. I want to use https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-php-client as a client to connect to graph DB, the reason I wanted to use this was to run cypher queries directly.

What changes should I make in the config/database.php to accommodate such condition and how do I access each database from the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom provider, for example in `App\Providers\Neo4jServiceProvider.php` and define 2 or more connections to the client :

```
class Neo4jServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(Client::class, function() {
            return ClientBuilder::create()
                ->addConnection('server1', getenv('NEO4J_1_HOST'))
                ->addConnection('server2', getenv('NEO4J_2_HOST'))
                ->build();
        });
    }
}
```

Then you register the provider in your application, add this to the `providers` array of the `config/app.php` file :

```
App\Providers\Neo4jServiceProvider::class,
```

Add the connections parameters for your neo4j dbs in the .env file.

Next, you can inject this service anywhere and query any db :

```
class MyController
{

  private $client;

  public function __construct(Client $client)
  {
    $this->client = $client;
  }

  public function doSomeQueries()
  {
    // Query DB 1
    $result = $this->client->run('MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)', null, null, 'server1'); 
    // Query DB 2
    $result2 = $this->client->run('MATCH (n) RETURN count(n)', null, null, 'server2'); 
}
```